# Datatable multi_select_filter como definir selects

Tags: javascript, datatables

Estoy utilzando una `datatable` pero quiero poder poder definir los `select` en las columnas que puedan aplicarse. Tengo un codigo pero me buscar por todas.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        initComplete: function () {
            this.api().columns().every( function () {
                var column = this;
                var select = $('<select><option value=""></option></select>')
                    .appendTo( $(column.header()) )
                    .on( 'change', function () {
                        var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
                            $(this).val()
                        );
 
                        column
                            .search( val ? '^'+val+'$' : '', true, false )
                            .draw();
                    } );
 
                column.data().unique().sort().each( function ( d, j ) {
                    select.append( '<option value="'+d+'">'+d+'</option>' )
                } );
            } );
        }
    } );
} );
```

```html
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script> 
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>



     <table id="example" class="table table-bordered table-sm" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
          <thead>
              <tr class="table-warning">
                  <th width="5%"># Indicador</th>
                  <th width="5%">Cantidad</th>
                  <th width="10%">Componente</th>
                  <th width="5%"></th>
              </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td> </td>
                <td> 4 </td>
                <td> Falso </td>
                <td> <button class='btn btn-danger btn-sm'>x </button>  </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td> </td>
                <td> 5 </td>
                <td> Falso </td>
                <td> <button class='btn btn-danger btn-sm'>x </button>  </td>
              </tr>
                <tr>
                <td> </td>
                <td> 6 </td>
                <td> TRUE </td>
                <td> <button class='btn btn-danger btn-sm'>x </button>  </td>
              </tr>
          </tbody>
      </table>
```

Espero haberme explicado bien.

Comment: No entiendo que intentas hacer.

Comment: en vez que me tenga todos los select, yo pueda definir que columna pueda tener este select option

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes lograr lo que quieres agregando una clase a las columnas donde quieres el select asi:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        initComplete: function () {
            this.api().columns(".buscar").every( function () {
                var column = this;
                var select = $('<select><option value=""></option></select>')
                    .appendTo( $(column.header()) )
                    .on( 'change', function () {
                        var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
                            $(this).val()
                        );
 
                        column
                            .search( val ? '^'+val+'$' : '', true, false )
                            .draw();
                    } );
 
                column.data().unique().sort().each( function ( d, j ) {
                    select.append( '<option value="'+d+'">'+d+'</option>' )
                } );
            } );
        }
    } );
} );
```

```html
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script> 
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>



     <table id="example" class="table table-bordered table-sm" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
          <thead>
              <tr class="table-warning">
                  <th width="5%"># Indicador</th>
                  <th width="5%" class="buscar">Cantidad</th>
                  <th width="10%" class="buscar">Componente</th>
                  <th width="5%"></th>
              </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td> </td>
                <td> 4 </td>
                <td> Falso </td>
                <td> <button class='btn btn-danger btn-sm'>x </button>  </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td> </td>
                <td> 5 </td>
                <td> Falso </td>
                <td> <button class='btn btn-danger btn-sm'>x </button>  </td>
              </tr>
                <tr>
                <td> </td>
                <td> 6 </td>
                <td> TRUE </td>
                <td> <button class='btn btn-danger btn-sm'>x </button>  </td>
              </tr>
          </tbody>
      </table>
```

Comment: thanks my budda :)